# How to exit from .profile command prompt

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to Unix environment. Please help me out on this issue. Thanks in advance.

I created new .profile for my id. Executed it by entering . .profile after which my bash prompt changed to something like this **mkis11@:/home/mkis11>** from **$bash>**.

I tried cd .. cd / cd . it all comes to **mkis11@:/>**, Even closed session and reopened. Still I get the same **mkis11@:/>**, Can someone tell me how do I get it back to **$bash>**.

regards,
Uvan

Answer (score 2):

`PS1="\s-\v\\$"` is the default bash prompt  (`shell-version[$#]`), or `bash-3.2$` for example.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/ can help you make awesome prompts.